# make element start "off" screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an element slide in on screen as soon as the user has scrolled down a bit. I already know how to make the animation, but there is no point in using the animation, if the element is already there. So how do I make an element that does not load when the page loads?

Thanks.

Comment: Use google? The css display property and negative margins will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="element"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#element {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var animation = function() {
    document.getElementById("element").style.display = "block";
}
```

The same goes if what you want is for it to slide, say, from the left. Your element should have a negative left and then you can use Javascript to change it.

```
#element {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.. Thanks @TJS